# ruby params split and multiple submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

I'm really new to ruby and I'm learning how to control getting params and dealing with it.

In case where

```
def create_pid
      @pid_form = Admin::PidCreationForm.new
      @person = @pid_form.submit(params[:pid])

      if @person
         redirect_to  edit_person(@person.id)

    end
```

In code like this, I want to get various numbers of pid rather than getting one per one form and submit them all.

How can I manipulate the ruby params for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you will want to send an array of `pids` like 
`{pids: [11,22,33]}`.

Then you can do `params.permit(:pids)`

This will give you all the values. You can also do a Active record call with it like `User.where(pid: params.permit[:pids])`

Answer (score 0):

You can have an array of numbers or text in the form:

```
<input type="text" name="pids[]" value="111">
<input type="text" name="pids[]" value="222">
```

In the controller, you should be able to get it via the params normally via `params[:pids]`.

Comment: acutally in param form in web is it okay to get 1123 3445 ... etc get various ids separated with spaces? then how does param deal with this kind of subjects when submitted. In status quo, it only gets one id per one form

Comment: You could, then you could just do a split for the ids. `pids.split` to get an array of it. But I just find it cleaner on the UI to be able to "add" rows of `pids`

Comment: you mean I can do such things? `params[:pids.split]` and `for each pid |pids.split|`  make forms?

Comment: Wait, what I've shown is for you to parse the values from a form already there- not for you to create the form with. I'm not sure what you're trying to do here anymore, why do you have the form in the controller?